# Change titles in a for loop for plt.plot and create 6x16 subplots

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, subplot

```
secondHold = np.zeros((96,30))

channel = ['channel' for x in range(96)]


for i in range (96):
    BlankBinsx = bins[blankposition,0:30,i]
    StimBinsx = bins[NonBlankPositions,0:30,i]
    meanx = BlankBinsx.mean(axis=0);
    stimmeanx = StimBinsx.mean(axis=0);
    for j in range(30):
        hold[i][j] = meanx[j];
        secondHold[i][j] = stimmeanx[j];
    plt.subplots(1, 1, sharex='all', sharey='all')
    plt.plot(hold[i], label='stimulus')
    plt.plot(secondHold[i], label='Blank Stimulus')
    plt.title('Channel x')
    plt.xlabel('time (ms)')
    plt.ylabel('Avg Spike Rate')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

I am creating 96 different graphs through a for-loop and I want it to also label the graphs (i.e., the first graph would be `'Channel 1'`, graph two `'Channel 2'` and so on. I tried `ax.set_title` but couldn't figure it out how to make it work with the string and numbers.

Also I'd like the graphs to print as a 6x16 subplots instead of 96 graphs in a column.

Answer (score 6):

You are creating a new figure each time in your for loop that's why you get 96 figures. I don't have your data so I can't provide a final figure but the following should work for you. The idea here is:

- Define a figure and an array of `axes` containing 6x16 subplots.
- Use `enumerate` on `axes.flatten` to iterate through the subfigures `ax` row wise and use `i` as the index to access the data.
- Use the field specifier `%d` to label the subplots iteratively.
- Put `plt.show()` *outside* the for loop

---

```
secondHold = np.zeros((96,30))
channel = ['channel' for x in range(96)]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=6, ncols=16, sharex='all', sharey='all')

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    BlankBinsx = bins[blankposition,0:30,i]
    StimBinsx = bins[NonBlankPositions,0:30,i]
    meanx = BlankBinsx.mean(axis=0);
    stimmeanx = StimBinsx.mean(axis=0);
    for j in range(30):
        hold[i][j] = meanx[j];
        secondHold[i][j] = stimmeanx[j];
    ax.plot(hold[i], label='stimulus')
    ax.plot(secondHold[i], label='Blank Stimulus')
    ax.set_title('Channel %d' %i)
    ax.set_xlabel('time (ms)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Avg Spike Rate')
    ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried doing running this but I am confused by the enumerate(axes.flatten()):, I need to iterate through the loop 96 times. I tried making two loops but that didnt work either.

Comment: `enumerate(axes.flatten()):` returns two things: first, the index starting from 0 and second, the actual axis object for each subplot one by one in a for loop

Comment: If you have 6 rows and 16 columns, then this for loop will indeed run 96 times. The value of `i` will go from 0 to 95. To convince yourself, you can add `print (i)` inside the for loop and it will print 0, 1, 2, .... , 94, 95

Comment: This code is working now but the subplots are all overlapping so it looks like a jumbled mess. I tried changing it to 32 rows and 3 columns and also adding plt.tight_layout() but neither of those are working

Comment: Also, if it put in the plt.show() outside the forloop it just shows up as one giant plot